# Add functionality to standard Pan Gesture Recognizer in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to keep track of where a finger is in a `UIScrollView`.
I have subclassed `UIScrollView` (see below) but unfortunately the gesture recognizer that I am adding is overriding the standard one.

As a result I get `NSLog(@"Pan")` to work but unfortunately the view doesn't scroll anymore.

How can I get *both* gestures recognizers to work at the same time?

Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}


- (void)pan:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Pan");
}
```

Comment: You don't say what you expect to happen when both things happen at the same time. Do you expect it to scroll *and* update your pan recognizer? If so, why not just listen to the scroll view delegate methods that get called when the view is scrolled?

Comment: I'd like the view to both scroll and record all the points touched (that I know I can retrieve through the `locationInView:` method). The scroll view delegate sounds interesting -I've never heard of that... I am quite new to iOS programming-, how would that work? Thanks.

Comment: I have found [this reference on scroll view delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) but I do not understand how to retrieve the coordinates of the touch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: this method works! You just need to set `canCancelContentTouches` as soon as possible (I do it in `viewDidLoad`).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: I have tried a new approach but unfortunately it doesn't fully work.

Instead of adding a gesture recognizer I am subclassing the `UIScrollView` and writing my own `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, etc methods.

This way I know where the user is touching BUT unfortunately the PanGestureRecognizer is triggering `touchesCancelled` every time I start to scroll *even after setting the `canCancelContentTouches` to NO*.

Does anybody know why? I have also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261543/scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview-without-triggering-touchescancelled).

Answer (score 14):

If you want it not to override the standard one you just have to allow both to be simultaneously recognized.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
    panRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
     return TRUE;
}


- (void)pan:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Pan");
}
```